# Point to point link with two Internet connections

Tags: routing, wireless, network, point-to-point

Thank you in advance for reading this question.
I have two buildings, let's say A and B, each connected to the Internet. Devices in A also need to access devices in B and vice-versa. The Internet connection is too slow for my purposes so a VPN isn't a possible solution. So I thought to create a PTP link between the two networks, using two Ubiquiti Litebeam Gen2 LBE‑5AC‑Gen2. Given this configuration (I hope it's readable):

[image: Network configuration image]

How should I make 192.168.2.x clients in building A access 192.168.0.x ones in building B and vice-versa? I thought about making two simple static routes on R1 and R2 for that.
Now the difficult question: is there a way to let every client in each building use both internet connections at once, in order to achieve greater speeds? Some sort of "distributed network balancing"? What changes at the network structure are needed? Is there any specific configurations for the Ubiquiti antennas?
Thank you again.

Comment: Any single traffic flow can only use one WAN connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static routes on each router will allow both sites to reach each other's resources.

Unfortunately, you can't "combine" or "load balance" your Internet connections.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concide answer. I feared that this wasn't possible since there can be a single gateway at a time which can't happen on this setup.

Answer (score 1):

In common case balancing of two ISP is possible, but there many depends on...

- One TCP (and in most cases other protocols) connection absolutely impossible to balance
- Because of IP security on some sites one client must not change IP (at least on the go), so for flawless Internet you must lock HTTP of one client to one ISP.

Is possible to overcome this limitations by using VPN to some router R3 placed in internet with an High speed connection

- But, TCP loss performance on packet reorder, so one connection (traffic flow) must be locked to one channel.

Mostly P2P protocols can be balanced well, bacause of it multipeer and multiconnection nature.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that "balancing" isn't possible with most traditional TCP connections and suggesting a solution. Unfortunately, using a third router in Internet with a fast connection isn't viable here.

Answer (score 0):

A physical point to point connectivity is required between two sites and at both end L3 interfàce need to configured and Route traffic between both sites

`Site A`

**Destination 192.168.0.0(siteA supernet) mask 255.255.0.0 pointing towards gateway siteB egress interfàce ip address**

`Site B`

**Destination 192.168.2.0(siteA supernet) mask 255.255.0.0 pointing towards gateway siteA egress interfàce ip address**